# Why getAllNetworks() return 0 when wifi or data mobile are disable?

Tags: android, null

I previously used `getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)` and never return `null` even when WiFi was off , but this was deprecated on api 23, So now I have this:

```
NetworkInfo isWifiOn = null;
Network[] networks = cm.getAllNetworks();
Log.i("sms", "size:"+networks.length);
for (Network network : networks) {
isWifiOn = cm.getNetworkInfo(network);
if (isWifiOn != null && isWifiOn.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) 
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

Here:

```
if(isWifiOn!=null){

}
else{
   //always enter here because networks.length is 0
}
```

When I used `getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)` always works even so WiFi was off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API docs for the `getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)`, it would return a `NetworkInfo` object with a [NetworkInfo.State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html) enum that indicates that there are no networks connected. See [ConnectivityManager's getNetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)) and [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html).

It is correct that the networks length is 0 because there are no networks connected.